# Regular Expression That Contains All Of The Specific Letters In Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression, which selects all the words that contains **all** (not! any) of the specific letters, just works fine on Notepad++.

Regular Expression Pattern;

```
^(?=.*B)(?=.*T)(?=.*L).+$
```

Input Text File;

```
AL
BAL
BAK
LABAT
TAL
LAT
BALAT
LA
AB
LATAB
TAB
```

And output of the regular expression in notepad++;

```
LABAT
BALAT
LATAB
```

As It is useful for Notepad++, I tried the same regular expression on java but it is simply failed.

Here is my test code;

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import com.lev.kelimelik.resource.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String patternString = "^(?=.*B)(?=.*T)(?=.*L).+$";

        String dictionary = 
                "AL" + "\n"
                +"BAL" + "\n"
                +"BAK" + "\n"
                +"LABAT" + "\n"
                +"TAL" + "\n"
                +"LAT" + "\n"
                +"BALAT" + "\n"
                +"LA" + "\n"
                +"AB" + "\n"
                +"LATAB" + "\n"
                +"TAB" + "\n";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(dictionary);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Match: " + m.group());
        }
    }

}
```

The output is **errorneous** as below;

```
Match: AL
BAL
BAK
LABAT
TAL
LAT
BALAT
LA
AB
LATAB
TAB
```

My question is simply, what is the java-compatible version of this regular expression?

Comment: The reason your regex worked in Notepad++ and not in Java is because NPP automatically applies multiline mode to all regexes.  If a regex is working for you in NPP and you want to export it to Java, add the MULTILINE flag.  (Adding the DOTALL flag, as you did, is equivalent to checking the ". matches newline" box in NPP, and I know you weren't doing that; you would have gotten the same result you did in Java.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Java-specific answer

In real life, we rarely need to validate *lines*, and I see that in fact, you just use the input as an array of test data. The most common scenario is reading input line by line and perform checks on it. I agree in Notepad++ it would be a bit different solution, but in Java, a single line should be checked separately.

That said, you should not copy the same approaches on different platforms. What is good in Notepad++ does not have to be good in Java.

I suggest this almost regex-free approach (`String#split()` still uses it):

```
String dictionary_str = 
        "AL" + "\n"
        +"BAL" + "\n"
        +"BAK" + "\n"
        +"LABAT" + "\n"
        +"TAL" + "\n"
        +"LAT" + "\n"
        +"BALAT" + "\n"
        +"LA" + "\n"
        +"AB" + "\n"
        +"LATAB" + "\n"
        +"TAB" + "\n";
String[] dictionary = dictionary_str.split("\n"); // Split into lines
for (int i=0; i<dictionary.length; i++)   // Iterate through lines
{
    if(dictionary[i].indexOf("B") > -1 && // There must be B
       dictionary[i].indexOf("T") > -1 && // There must be T
       dictionary[i].indexOf("L") > -1)   // There must be L
    {
        System.out.println("Match: " + dictionary[i]); // No need matching, print the whole line
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iFagKr)

## Original regex-based answer

You should not rely on `.*` ever. This construct causes backtracking issues all the time. In this case, you can easily optimize it with a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html):

```
^(?=[^B]*+B)(?=[^T]*+T)(?=[^L]*+L)
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^B]*+B)` - right at the start of the string, check for at least one `B` presence that may be preceded with 0 or more characters other than `B`
- `(?=[^T]*+T)` -  *still* right at the start of the string, check for at least one `T` presence that may be preceded with 0 or more characters other than `T`
- `(?=[^L]*+L)`- **still** right at the start of the string, check for at least one `L` presence that may be preceded with 0 or more characters other than `L`

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/P7iY3D):

```
String patternString = "^(?=[^B]*+B)(?=[^T]*+T)(?=[^L]*+L)";
String[] dictionary = {"AL", "BAL", "BAK", "LABAT", "TAL", "LAT", "BALAT", "LA", "AB", "LATAB", "TAB"};
for (int i=0; i<dictionary.length; i++)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dictionary[i]);
    if(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println("Match: " + dictionary[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Match: LABAT
Match: BALAT
Match: LATAB
```

Comment: And the output you get is wrong because you are testing it wrong.  I am adding the code now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really waiting for it but it will be more useful if you also gave an explanation for your answer, not only for me but also to the users that get here from google for the same problem. Thanks or your reply.

Comment: I hope I added enough details. I did not add any performance testing, it is a known fact that negated character classes perform much better than `.*` (especially in Java). See  also [this post: *Does the Java regex library optimize for any characters .\*?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33809099/3832970).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a fair and useful detailed answer.

Comment: Yeah sure, just done, and you also could do the same for the question that if you think this question is valueable for other programmers around the web.

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu: I have, that's why you do not have -1.

Comment: There's some good general advice here, but it doesn't explain why the OP's code didn't work.  Try plugging your regexes into *his* code, and you'll get very different results.  You "solved" his problem by changing the input from a multiline string to an array of individual words.  All he really needed to do was add the `MULTILINE` flag instead of the `DOTALL` flag.

Comment: @AlanMoore: You made me rethink the current approach. I added another approach to solving the original problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Pattern` to:

`String patternString = ".*(?=.*B)(?=.*L)(?=.*T).*";`

Output

```
Match: LABAT
Match: BALAT
Match: LATAB
```

Comment: Thanks for the line terminator update, I've updated the Pattern.compile parameter however, again the output is not valid. Can you check out the code again? This time, the result brings up all the words which is still errorneous.

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu sorry confused the requirements. My new answer is probably more like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I did not debug your situation, but I think your problem is caused by matching the entire string rather than individual words.

You're matching `"AL\nBAL\nBAK\nLABAT\n"` plus some more. Of course that string has all the required characters. You can see it in the fact that your output only contains one `Match:` prefix.

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression) answer. You need to use `Pattern.MULTILINE`.